# Blender Eevee. I can´t properly see the smoke

Tags: eevee-render-engine

[image]

When I render smoke in this project, in the viewport it doesn´t look as I expect , and when I render it (With previous baked) I can´t barely see it. It doesn´t have anything to do with the mesh or the boxes sourrounding it, I´ve checked it. I thing is should be something about the view options. Any help?

Comment: you should post the screenshot of the shader node of the domain, so it's possible to check what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Ah yes, smoke and Eevee. It's tough, that's for sure. It's hard to tell exactly what the issue because you need to show the shaders, and the smoke domain settings. You also need to make sure that the smoke is lit. Sometimes you need to use a fair bit of light. You can make the smoke emit but not directly through the principled volume shader. My recommendation would be to watch Iridisium tutorial on making a simple explosion in Blender.

You also need to check your render settings for volumetrics. Having a clipping distance to far or too close can prevent you from seeing your smoke. Finally, you might need to play around with density, the emitter, and the division value. Too high a setting can make for wispy smoke if you don't change other settings.

Good luck. I have found the smoke simulator very tough to use. There are some great tutorials out there though.